# How To Do Zero-Copy Deserialization of Recursive Enums with Serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm not even sure it's possible with serde, but what I'm trying to do is something along the following:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub enum Tree<'a> {
    Zero,
    One(&'a Tree<'a>),
    Two(&'a Tree<'a>, &'a Tree<'a>),
    Three(&'a Tree<'a>, &'a Tree<'a>, &'a Tree<'a>),
}
```

Is this possible using specific serde attributes (like `#[serde(borrow)]`, etc.)?  Is it required to do a custom implementation of `Deserialize`?  Or is it not something serde can do?

Comment: Not possible. The `&`s are at some level just fancy pointers, and pointers get decided by your allocator or stack depth at runtime, they can't be already contained in the data you're deserializing (ignoring insane mmap hacks). Thus `Tree` can't be zero-copy deserialized. In fact, the only two ways I can think of to deserialize `Tree` at all, are to a) leak memory b) implement a seeded deserializer that holds a reference to a bump allocator (neither is zero-copy). Side note: if you've got free choice of the binary format, you're probably better of looking at something like rkyv.

Comment: @Caesar you seem to be confusing zero-copy and zero-allocation and so does OP I think. With the former very well being possible.

Comment: I suppose you define zero-copy as "Copies no large strings or byte buffers around"? I suppose you can do that, but I don't like that definition. If I ask for a zero-copy deserialization *of Tree*, then I expect to be handed a `&Tree` that points into the serialized data (which is of course not possible).

Answer (score 0):

You can't because something has to own all the new `Tree` objects.

You can however create a similar structure:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, serde::Serialize, serde::Deserialize)]
pub enum Tree<'a> {
    Zero(&'a str),
    One(Box<Tree<'a>>),
    Two(Box<(Tree<'a>, Tree<'a>)>),
    Three(Box<(Tree<'a>, Tree<'a>, Tree<'a>)>),
}
```

I added a `&'a str` argument to `Zero` to have some use for that lifetime, else you could just get rid of it all together.

`Box`es are needed because else we would have an infinite size requirement.

This is still zero-copy since we're not copying any data from the underlaying array. It is however not zero-allocation which might work with some hacks or in special cases but generally is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the closest possible thing to what I wanted to do without allocation:

```rust
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
pub enum Tree<'a> {
    Zero,
    One(&'a [u8]),
    Two(&'a [u8], &'a [u8]),
    Three(&'a [u8], &'a [u8], &'a [u8]),
}
```

Then each individual slice would be deserialized into `Tree` on descent.  As @Caesar pointed out this would not technically be zero-copy, though, depending on your definition (I think it's kind of a gray area).